# How to ultimately disable a button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I want to build an interactive page within a website. On this page i want to put a list of items, that people can choose from, in order to bring one of them to a certain event/party.
Once a user choses an item via a confirm pop up box, i want the button to be ultimately disabled, even if the user opens the page again or another user opens the page.
I want this event to happen within a conditional statement in JavaScript somewhat like this:

```
if (confirm("Do you really want to bring this item to the event/party?") == true) {

HERE I WANT TO PUT THE CODE THAT IS NECESSARY!

} else {

}
```

Comment: "even if the user opens the page again or another user opens the page" <- you can't do this with client-side code.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on JavaScript to do this for you... I'd use a server-side solution where you can store who's selected what in a database (permanent storage). JavaScript alone can't do what you're asking because it only interacts with the current session. Yes, you could build an AJAX solution (this will give you live results and you can disable the button).

Comment: Hey Chris, thx for the answer! I will try to figure it out. Are u familiar with solutions to problems similar to mine, so i could get back to you if i'm having trouble?

Comment: This is actually rather simple, just store something on the server that says the button is disabled and check it on every pageload. This is what just about every website in the universe does, using a database to store state, comments, whatever.

Comment: @adeneo thx for your comment! So is it possible to store new data in my database(on my server) with javascript? If so, how do i do it?

Comment: It's not, javascript executes in the browser on the users computer, it has no access to your server (in this case), but you can send an ajax request to the server or reload the page with a form submit to send data to the server.

Comment: @adaneo OK! i will figure out as much as possible for myself now, first. Your answers did help me a lot!!! thx :) and regards

Comment: @Big Chris your answer obviously provided the best solution in the first place! I'm just not experienced enough to understand it right away. Thx a lot!!! regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with pure JavaScript, because JavaScripts loads everytime the page gets refreshed. Are you getting your data from a database? If so, you could add another field to your table e.g. "party" with the name "active". If the user clicks on a button, the party would be inactive and not showing up anymore.

But as I said, I think it's not possible with only JavaScript.

PS: Greetings from Germany ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with JavaScript alone. You will need to employ some server-side scripting and (ideally) a database to store who has selected what so that you can "prevent" someone else from selecting the same item.

Your system should also include a user registration process so that you can tie your products to events and then tie users to the products they have selected for the event.

Thus:

User registers -> they select an event -> they select a currently available product -> some confirmation occurs which then flags the database that anyone else is unable to select this product for the chosen event. The confirmation can be achieved with standard forms processing methods or AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

> Once a user choses an item via a confirm pop up box, i want the button to be ultimately disabled, even if the user opens the page again or another user opens the page.

Javascript can't preserve these types of `states`. It only runs in users browsers. You can't save it to cookie either. Saved cookie is only useful for certain users certain browser. You have to save this data in your server (preferably in database) from where you can read `this item is chose by a user`. And then you can decide from client when to disable the button.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I have a better understanding of how to solve my problem now. regards